# Resetting password using express and JWT token

Tags: express, jwt

I am trying to reset the user password using the following code and Postman. 
But what I realised is that there is no user after I generate the token. the console is saying `null`;

```
// Reset User Password
exports.resetPassword = function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    reset_password_token: req.body.token,
    reset_password_expires: {
      $gt: Date.now()
    }
  }).exec(function (err, user) {
    console.log('this user: ' + user)
    if (!err && user) {
      if (req.body.newPassword === req.body.verifyPassword) {
        user.hash_password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.newPassword, 10);
        user.reset_password_token = undefined;
        user.reset_password_expires = undefined;
        user.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(422).send({
              message: err
            });
          } else {
            console.log(user.hash_password)
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(422).send({
          message: 'Passwords do not match'
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.'
      });
    }
  });
};
```

This is how I use it in Postman

```
{           
            "newPassword": "cocacola",
            "verifyPassword": "cocacola",
            "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YjI3NjAyNDAwOWI1NDA5ZjMwNzAzZWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzA5NjA2NDEwOTN9.1LjroayiTWDNevShnH30n3LxUGCrazmTaJlHgOUNvJ0"
}
```

and the response in Postman is message from status 400

Comment: Do you mean `console.log('this user: ' + user)` is `null` ?

Comment: If not above, then you should be getting runtime error - like "cannot read property `hash_password`of `undefined`" because, this might be failing `console.log(user.hash_password)`

Comment: @SureshPrajapati you're right console.log('this user: ' + user) is null

Comment: Are you sure that this particular record exists in the database? Can you attach the query result for above token?